# Google Translate API Requests Limit

Tags: google-translate

I know the Google Translate API has a limit of 5,000 characters per request, but how many requests are allowed under a certain period of time?

Comment: Need to update the correct answer, v1 has been deprecated.

Comment: Currently in 2020 there is a content quota saying `6,000,000 characters 60 seconds  per project and user` and `For requests using an API key, the client IP address is used to enforce this limit`. Does this mean when used e.g. in an Android app using the same API key every user has this rate limit per 60 seconds?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[It seems to be 100,000](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-ajax-search-api/7EupaX_9QkM/discussion).

Though this can be increased. (Refer discussion in the link)

Answer (score 4):

With the (paid) google translate API v2, one can set different quotas, like a Per-User Limit, which throttles the maximum number of characters a user can send for translation / second. You can set this as low as you want, i.e. 10.0 characters/second/user.

Remark
There is no more free google translate API: V1 was shut down on Dec. 1, 2011, and for V2 you have to pay. See: [Google language APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/language/)

Answer (score 0):

By default, it's 5 requests/second/user and 200,000 requests/day (Billable limit) but you can increase the limit requests/second/user in your console web developer google (at https://code.google.com/apis/console/).

1. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth, then select APIs and select Translate API.
2. On the API's info page, select the Quota link near the API name.
3. Click the Set per-user limits... button to increase your limits.

IMPORTANT : if you don't see the line "BigQuery API" -> 5 requests/second/user is because you don't have a professional account gmail.
Also : You have to enable Biling (professional account or not).