# C# Google Translate API: The remote server returned an error: (429) Too Many Requests

Tags: c#, webclient, google-translate

While I am using google API for translating data in C# code using the [google translate API](https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=%7B0%7D&tl=%7B1%7D&dt=t&q=%7B2%7D), after translating some of content, I am getting the error:

> The remote server returned an error: (429) Too Many Requests

I am using the below code:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
                    outputData=wc.DownloadString(url);
                }
```

Comment: what is your question? the acceptable rate of anonymous requests is defined at the discretion of the service provider. unlimited commercial use is possible and subject to licencing.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/4405861/1132334

Comment: Take a look at Polly to automatically do a "wait and retry" when you get this error. https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly