# translate.google.com requests limit from Python requests module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, google-translate, google-translation-api

I have a small script making a request to http://translate.google.com/m?hl=%s&sl=%s&q=%s as my `base_link` however I've seemed to have surpassed the requests limit

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

I am looking for what the limit is for google translate. The answers out there point to the Google Translate API limits however not the limit if one is directly accessing from Python's `requests` module.

Let me know if I can provide some more information.

Comment: There's [`googletrans`](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) module, which already has implementation of API requests.

Comment: I'm trying to limit module dependencies for my program hence the use of `requests` but your solution provides a good alternative if needed

Comment: Just compare, if same issue on that lib, than there's no solution except proxies

Answer (score 1):

The request you are submitting using the url http://translate.google.com/m?hl=%s&sl=%s&q=%s is using the free service via http://translate.google.com. The limits you have been seeing online is related to [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas) which is under Google Cloud Platform. These 2 are totally different from each other.

Currently, there is no public document discussing the limits in using googletrans. But, Googletrans will block your IP address once the system detects that you have been exploiting the free translation service by submitting huge amounts of requests, resulting in

> HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

.

You can use Google Cloud Platform’s [Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/quickstart#translate_translate_text-python) which is a paid service. Using this, you can avoid low limits set in googletrans which will give you more flexibility with the amount of requests you can submit.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4405861/11985743), the content quota (on the API) is 6,000,000 characters for 60 seconds  per project and user. Therefore it is safe to assume that Google would protect the private API with much less than this. Google will not release the numbers for the private API (because it is supposed to only be used by the website itself, therefore they aren't willing to give any information about it since only they are supposed to know it anyways). If you need a more specific answer, I suggest you try and find
more accurate API limits and assume it is much less than whatever number it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but according to [this source](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing) it seems to be 500,000 characters for free user.

Comment: I had much less in my request. I'm looking for the NUMBER of requests rather than the data inside, do you have that information?